# How to set Google maps marker size dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to size my marker by zooming, but it seems not to work here is the code for a better overview:

```
function Icon(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(30, 30); // scaled size
    //this.origin = new google.maps.Point(0,0); // origin
    //this.anchor = new google.maps.Point(0, 0); // anchor
}

var icon1 = new Icon('img/marker-test.png');

        map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
        if(map.zoom === 18){
            //marker.setIcon(test);
            console.log('check');
            marker.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(300, 300);

        } else {
            //marker.setIcon(icon1);
        }
    });
```

Somebody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer, a couple suggestions:

- You have used `map.zoom === 18`which is not valid. It should be `map.getZoom() === 18`
- `marker.scaledSize` is invalid as `scaledSize` is the property of `Icon` object. Ref:[Icon Object Specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)

  If you need to set the marker size dynamically, you need to specify the marker image(while creating marker) via icon property and not as a string or leave empty(to show default marker).

Scale wont work on default marker. So you need to provide your own custom image for the marker.

**Scale vs Size**

Scale transforms the marker image and size specifies the canvas size of the image. Setting size property of a small marker image will not show you any zoom effect of the marker image. However if the marker image is large enough and that it was previously been drawn with downscaling, upscaling will work fine.

If you just scale the image and not set the size, the marker image will zoom in the prespecifed size. That is some portions of the marker image will not be visible.

To put in easy words, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8z0yyeq/1/). Try changing zoom to 18 and over and then back to 15 and below.

Comment: Thanks man, I totally forgot to put to specify the icon property! And thanks for the further information :) You helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

Try with the correct `getZoom` map method.

```
if (map.getZoom() === 18) {
    ...
}
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map